# Image with opacity like background image for a windows control

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a image (png file) with opacity 35%, i want for example:

Set the opacity image to a panel BackgroundImage, the panel is over a form with backcolor black, i thought (like in photoshop happen) that the opacity of the image will do a more clear color in the panel area, but the real result is that panel appear entire white, someone know how i can do this efect in windows forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really understand the question.  But it sounds like you're trying to blend an image into the background.  Check out my code in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2b4c5c41-8f3c-4e81-9169-78082b80c747) to see how to use ColorMatrix to achieve this.

Comment: It's a tricky workaround, but I have not encountered a better method. 1+