# Fade in picturebox in VB

Tags: vb.net

How do I make a picturebox fade in after a timer

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

picturebox1.opacity = false

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image with opacity like background image for a windows control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457933/image-with-opacity-like-background-image-for-a-windows-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opacity is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox. You can't have the same effect like forms. But you can do this:

PictureBox1.Visible = False